# MYSQL, how to get data with ID above 4

Tags: mysql

Halloprogrammer friend!

I have a table, named "testtabel"
the content and form as follows

```
|ID | DATA1        | DATA2 |
| 1 | hallo        | iya   |
| 2 | iya          | hallo |
| 3 | hallo        | iya   |
| 4 | iya          | hallo |
| 5 | iya          | hallo |
| 6 | hallo        | iya   |
| 7 | apa          | hallo |
| 8 | nama         | dari  |
| 9 | iya          | hallo |
```

I want to display two concurrent data, which is the ID above 4 with DATA1=hallo, DATA2=iya and DATA1=iya, DATA2=hallo
so the results

```
| 5 | iya         | hallo    |
| 6 | hallo     | iya        |
| 9 | iya         | hallo    |
```

please help, thank you

Comment: what about learning sql queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM testtabel
WHERE id > 4
AND ((data1 = 'iya' AND data2 = 'hallo') OR (data1 = 'hallo' AND data2 = 'iya'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM testtabel
WHERE id > 4
AND ("hallo" in (data1, data2) AND "iya" in (data1, data2) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, DATA1, DATA2 FROM testtabel WHERE ID > 4 
AND ((DATA1 = 'hallo' AND DATA2 = 'iya') OR (DATA1 = 'iya' AND DATA2 = 'hallo'))
```

Take a look at the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/) to learn more.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This won't get line 6.